# Passing List in Pgfplotstableset

Tags: pgfplots, lists, pgfplotstable, foreach

I'm pretty new to LaTex, so please forgive my sloppy code. I'm trying to create a table from a csv file, and pass a list of colors in so that LaTex will color each cell of the a column of the table differently depending on the corresponding element in the list. I can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}
\RequirePackage{listofitems}


\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
    ColA, ColB, ColC
    0.17, 0.91, 0.67
    0.15, 0.17, 0.92
    0.48, 0.1, 0.28
\end{filecontents*}




\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    ]{test.csv}
    \def\mylistOne{green, blue, orange}
    \readlist*\mylistTwo{\mylistOne}
    \newcounter{myCounter}
    \setcounter{myCounter}{-1}
    \foreachitem\x\in\mylistTwo[]{
        \stepcounter{myCounter}
        \pgfplotstableset{
            every row \themyCounter column 1/.style={
                postproc cell content/.append style={
                /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={\cellcolor{\x}}{},
            }
        }
    }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it going to repeat the colors if there are more rows?

Comment: No, the length of the list will match the number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created another column to have ease of access to the colors since the numbers match

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
ColA, ColB, ColC
0.17, 0.91, 0.67
0.15, 0.17, 0.92
0.48, 0.1, 0.28
}\mytable
\def\mylistOne{green, blue, orange}

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set list/.expand once=\mylistOne]{colors}{\mytable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns={ColA,ColB,ColC},
  row setter/.style={
    every row no #1/.style={
      before row={%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{colors}\of\mytable%
      \expandafter\rowcolor\expandafter{\pgfplotsretval}%
      }
    }
  },
  row setter/.list={0,1,2}
]\mytable


\end{document}
```

[image]

For single column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,colortbl}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
ColA, ColB, ColC
0.17, 0.91, 0.67
0.15, 0.17, 0.92
0.48, 0.1, 0.28
}\mytable
\def\mylistOne{green, blue, orange}

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/set list/.expand once=\mylistOne]{colors}{\mytable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns={ColA,ColB,ColC},
  columns/ColB/.style={
    postproc cell content/.code={%
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{colors}\of\mytable%
      \begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}%
      {\noexpand\cellcolor{\pgfplotsretval}##1}}\temp%
    }
  }
]\mytable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that only one of the columns is colored?

Comment: @KevinGregory Added one possibility